# laravel public variable for different controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I want to set a public variable so I can use it in different controllers. I tried this but it is not successful.

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
 public $TravelId;
public function __construct()
{
 $this->TravelId=0;
}
}
```

then I used the same variable in another contorller

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
public function index($cus_id)
{
    //unique key for each user
    $this->TravelId = $cus_id;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your controllers extend `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` class by default, so you can add a property on this class and access it on all your controllers:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    /**
     * Your static property
     */
    public static $travelId;
}
```

Then you can access it on another controller:

```php
self::$travelId = $cus_id;
```

Comment: do I have to add the use to you added.

Comment: @Jalloh just add your property to the existing `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` class

Comment: It worked but it did not solve my problem. I want to use it in another contoller to pass the value cus_id. I will edit my question. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jalloh as I mentioned you have to declare it as `static`.